Is there a word for a story that you can put into a different context with it retaining its original message/meaning?
An example is in the play Death and the Maiden by Ariel Dorfman, he states at the beginning that one could imagine the play taking place in Chile after the Pinochet dictatorship, but that you could actually apply it to any country or place that has just experienced the fall of a dictatorship. Is there a word for this kind of storytelling? Where it can be both specific to one context but also generalized to others?

Would universal theme do?

Such stories are often called timeless, eternal, ageless (The Ageless Story was a retelling of the life of Jesus which Christians consider eternally relevant) or tale as old as time (Disney's Beauty and the Beast). Do you want something more technical or literary though?

It sounds close to a meme.

Allegorical is also a candidate, depending on the context:
Cambridge Dictionary -allegorical

In or relating to a story, play, picture, or other work in which the
characters and events represent moral, religious, or political
qualities or ideas:


An allegorical novel/painting/play

My father enjoyed Melville's allegorical seafaring tales.



Metaphorical might do:
Cambridge Dictionary - metaphorical

Not having real existence but representing some truth about a
situation or other subject:
Her second novel is written in a very metaphorical style.

